# Docusign PHP SDK - Fill Template pre-defined data label value

Tags: php, docusignapi

UPDATE:

As it turns out, I need to enable this setting for data to show up, and using tabs is the correct thing to do.

**When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients**

=================================================================

Not sure why this one is not mentioned in API properly ... but how does one go about filling template's custom data label with template?

So, I create a template like this:

```php
$envelope_definition = new EnvelopeDefinition([
            'status'      => 'sent',
            'template_id' => $args['template_id'],
        ]);
```

then I create a signer:

```php
 $signer = new TemplateRole([
            'email'     => $args['signer_email'],
            'name'      => $args['signer_name'],
            'role_name' => 'signer',
        ]);
```

Here is where the disconnect happened, where do I add a pre-defined template value? I tried two things so far: 
1. Add `tabs` to `$signer` like so, but by doing so, it ereases all field value in the final document,

```php
new Tabs([
                    "text_tabs" => [
                        new Text([
                            "tab_label" => "price",
                            "value"     => "123456789",
                        ]),
                    ],
                ]),
```

2. Call `$envelope_definition->setCustomFields()` , like this :

```php
$envelope_definition->setCustomFields(new CustomFields([
            'text_custom_fields' => [
                'price' => new Text([
                    'tab_label'     => 'price',
                    'custom_tab_id' => 'price',
                    'value'         => '123456789',
                ]),
            ],
        ]));
```

It will throw me a C# error, which I don't understand at all:

```
Error while requesting server, received a non successful HTTP code [400] with response Body:  O:8:\"stdClass\":2:{s:9:\"errorCode\";s:20:\"INVALID_REQUEST_BODY\";s:7:\"message\";s:718:\"The request body is missing or improperly formatted. Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[API_REST.Models.v2_1.textCustomField]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\r\nPath 'customFields.textCustomFields.price', line 1, position 45.\";}"
```

API docs seems to be focusing on creating template and values adhoc ... anyone have something that works? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you please share what you mean by erases all fields value in the final document?

Comment: like sender name, signer name, all gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This valid PHP example](https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/master/src/Controllers/Examples/eSignature/EG017SetTemplateTabValues.php) shows how to prepopulate template tab values while creating an envelope.

Comment: Additional helpful link supporting above answer: https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-php/blob/bb7ea1d40220ce815daa7be685274c927c4dbf49/src/Services/Examples/eSignature/SetTemplateTabValuesService.php#L73

Answer (score 0):

You didn't follow the example correctly.

You didn't create a \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TextCustomField object.

Here it is from Amit's link:

```
    # Create an envelope custom field to save the our application's
    # data about the envelope
    $custom_field = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\TextCustomField([
        'name' => 'app metadata item',
        'required' => 'false',
        'show' => 'true', # Yes, include in the CoC
        'value' => '1234567']);
    $custom_fields = new \DocuSign\eSign\Model\CustomFields([
        'text_custom_fields' => [$custom_field]]);
    $envelope_definition->setCustomFields($custom_fields);
```